# Set First day of the range as Initial Inventory + Production - Sales = Inventory (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax

My challenge has been how to
01 - set Initial Inventory (considering the first day of the column);
02 - From the second day on, have Forecast (Previsão)  - Sales (Vendas) = Balance. So 3 columns for each day

The way it is now, it repeats Initial Inventory throughout the days.
[image]

Here's the goal I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Here's how the tables are related:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to approach it with an unrelated helper table, that would contain 2 columns and 4 rows. Here's an example based on Contoso data.

Here's the helper table. Column `Item ID` is used for sorting result columns as well:

[image]

And now comes the magic:

```
Helper measure =
VAR minDate =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( DimDate[Datekey] ), ALLSELECTED ( DimDate ) )
VAR curDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( DimDate[Datekey] )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Helper[Item ID] ),
        1, IF ( curDate = minDate, [Opening Inventory Qty], BLANK () ),
        2, [Production Qty],
        3, - [Sales Qty],
        4, [Closing Inventory Qty]
    )
```

Here's an explanation:

- minDate is used to get initial date on the visual
- curDate is used to get current date
- Next I check, which column from the helper table the measure is calculated for using `SWITCH` function
- using `SWITCH`, I return different formula, based on helper column type
- for Opening inventory, I only return a value when current date is equal to initial date. Otherwise, I return `BLANK()` - that's why Opening inventory only appears on the first date

The matrix visual is built using `Product name` in rows; `Year`, `month`, `day` and `Item` (from the helper table) in columns, and the `Helper measure` from above.

Here's a the result (don't mind quantities, it's a sample data):
[image]

**EDIT:**
For completeness' sake, here's how the model looks. Notice that the `Helper` table is not related to any other table:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Incredible from what I can see on the prints. I still couldn't get there. How would I go about creating the measures, such as Opening Inventory Qty? Thanks a million!

Comment: @AntonioSantos difficult to say without seeing your model and knowing your data. Do you have a table that shows inventory quantity on each day? Or does it have to be calculated dynamically?

Comment: Hi! Incredible from what I can see on the prints. I still couldn't get there. How would I go about creating the measures, such as Opening Inventory Qty? Opening Inv. and Production are from the same column. What differentiates them is that Opening Inv is the one with earliest date. Salesv comes from a Related Table. Thanks a million!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YE2mSPGgvG2Dhyi4alzTbWyNVTPTXvp9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, sorry, but it's too difficult having to figure out names that you don't understand.

Comment: Hi! The Opening Inventory has to be calculated, 'coz it comes in the same column as Production. What differentiates one from the other is that the Opening Inv. are the ones whose date is the earliest

Comment: Ok, so where exactly are you having difficulties? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm having difficulty including the Sales (which is from a different table - related with Production tb by date) and calculating Closing Inv.

Comment: Just added how tables are related with a couple of notes.

Comment: I need english description of each column that is relevant - for instance, I don't know what Valor column means. Is it production quantity, is it stock quantity? If stock, is it at the beginning of the day, end of day? I would not want to spend time figuring this out by myself. This is far beyond the scope of SO questions. If you want my help, please make it easy for me to understand.

Comment: You're right. Will get back with a translated version of it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's a translated version half the way gone - attempt wise: https://drive.google.com/file/d/156jqQf88WR2m48xPZawyKPuG-2RQDDM0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AntonioSantos I looked at your model. You don't see any sales, because your sales are all from first of February, while your date slicer is from 8th to 14th. You don't have opening inventory data, you only have production. You need information how much stock was there at the beginning for the report to work. Either that or the other way round - you have stock, but not production numbers. Your product list table - this would be best if it only contained a single row per each item.

Comment: Got sales for this date interval and limited Product List to unique values only. As for Opening Inv. it's the values from the earliest date in the Production dataset. The other values/dates are production qty's. Two remaining questions are: How is Closing Inv Measure calculated? How do I calculate/separate Production from the earliest dates in the dataset?

Comment: If the first date is opening stock, then you don't have production for the first date, right? Be that as it may, you need to sum values in Production table over several days. You can do it using CALCULATE / FILTER combination. Pseudocode: CALCULATE(SUM(Production[Amount], FILTER(ALL(Calendar[Date]), Calendar[Date] >= Start_date && Calendar[Date] <= Current_date))

Comment: Thank you very much! Still got a couple of points, but I'll open a new thread!